# Javascript function not defined in FireFox only - indeed_clk is not defined

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm at a loss to figure out why a JavaScript function is not defined.

It works on all browsers, and all versions of FireFox on my dev machine. But the error occurs for some users running FireFox.

The  external JavaScript include file is provided by Indeed.com.

The include file that contains the function definition (indeed_clk) is

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.indeed.com/ads/apiresults.js"></script>
```

This line appears immediately after the head elememt

Further down the page, the indeed_clk function is referenced using the following pattern

```
<a onmousedown = "indeed_clk(this,&#39;7832&#39;);" href="landing page..." >Click to view</a>
```

The error message is "indeed_clk is not defined"

A sample page that demonstrates the rendered html and Javascript code is
http://www.contractsforgeeks.com/TechJobs/All_States/All_Cities.aspx

Any suggestions as to why the function would not be defined in FF, and not work only for certain machine configurations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
indeed_clk(this,&#39;7832&#39;)
```

To:

```
indeed_clk(this,'7832');"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It did not work, however.

BTW
I was using MVC 3 Razor View engine to render the html

By default Razor HtmlEncodes everything.

It's also possible to persuade Razor not to HtmlEncode


I replaced 
 @(model.IndeedScript);

with
 @(new HtmlString(Model.IndeedScript)).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution/workaround to the problem, but still don't understand why the error occurs.

It seems that the presence of an error Handler causes an error (but only in FF for some users)

An error handler was hooked up

```
(document).ready ( errorHandling);

function errorHandling()
{
   window.onerror = function (message, url, line) {
        var msg = message + "\n" + " url:" + url + "\nline:" + line;
        alert(msg);
}
```

Disabling the error handling enabled the missing indeed_clk function to be found.

Comment: Is there still a page showing the problem somewhere?  Hard to say what the JS file looked like before your changes...

Comment: The problem no longer occurs, but all  I did was comment out one line of code. 

View source on the sample page listed above , and look for a commented out call to errorHandling. That's the only difference.